# Send email to selected users in the gallery via checkbox - Power Apps

Tags: powerapps

I have a list of users who submitted their timecards for a week showing in a gallery. I have a checkbox next to each item. I want to be able to approve the selected records from the gallery and send email to each one of them. The email should be personalized showing their names and respective manager details.

Comment: The ForAll statement does the trick ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, in the Data section, add Office365Outlook as a data source.

Then, in the Checkbox's OnCheck property, put the following:

```
Office365Outlook.SendEmail(
    "EMAIL ADDRESS; SEPARATE MULTIPLE ADDRESSES WITH SEMICOLON",
    "EMAIL SUBJECT LINE",
     "EMAIL BODY",
     {Cc:"CC EMAIL ADDRESS"}
```